# How to modify and debug a method of third party dll in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, .net-assembly, decompiling

Is it possible to view code of third party dll in Visual Studio 2015? can I able modify that method in VS2015. Are there any NUGET package available? Are there any Visual Studio Extensions available to do code modification in third party dll? Any free or Paid Services available?

Comment: you want to view the code or debug it (as title suggest)? That's two different things

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want to modify the existing method in 3rd party dll and debug it.

Comment: then [https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy](dnSpy) is the best tool

Comment: given Reference  link above is not working

Comment: then search for dnSpy on GitHub

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool called ILSpy. It’s a free download

Or this might help you 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/05b3cf5d-ead3-4274-88f5-6e8cbda8e8d8/decompiling-a-dll-file-to-view-source-code?forum=msbuild

Comment: Any best third party tool available with more features?